# "It is to be questioned" versus "it has to be questioned"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Which sentence is correct?

> In general it has to be questioned [...].

> In general it is to be questioned [...].

I am not sure which is correct, but I think "it has to be" is correct.

Comment: What's the context? It's possible to build sentences around both fragments, but the one with *is* sounds more contrived.

Answer (score 3):

It **has to** be questioned is the correct usage here, but you could also use

> It **must** be questioned

Answer (score -1):

'has to' is used when there is a compulsion, say a threat or an order or a non-negotiable task.

Example- Say, your friend asks you to come with him and you deny by saying-'No, I **am to** go to pick my nephew from school.' He would say- 'But your brother too can go and pick him, you please come with me, it's urgent.' You agree and call your brother to inform about the situation.

Case2: You deny your friend by saying,'I **have to** go to pick my nephew as my brother is out of town.' Your friend understands and leave.

*Now depending on the context of your question, both 'has to' and 'is to' can be applied.*

Comment: 'has to' is used much more widely than just in the cases of threats and orders. And there is no indication that there is a threat and order in the OP's sentence. I don't think this answer is that helpful.

Comment: More widely usage need not be technically correct. Btw, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I wish one might explain the reason for the downvote.